# Dynamic created ImageView can not be get by id Android?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, imageview, android-imageview

i am getting error while getting imageview control with its id

error is,

```
12-13 08:06:56.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/26 }} to activity {com.example.hakslogin/com.example.hakslogin.QuestionActivityDynamic}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
```

code for getting it is,

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                String imgid=String.valueOf(requestCode); 
                img = (ImageView) findViewById(requestCode);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
}
```

i have not mentioned here code for creating imageview dynamically but my imageview id is 0.

getting error on line ,

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(requestCode);
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: where you call startActivityForResult() method, post the code also.

Answer (score 1):

.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
You are casting Button named img to image view

try renaming the set id to another int

Comment: i got this issue just after posting but thanks for your reply